# PrimeFaces p:fileupload

Tags: primefaces

Size limit attribute in p:fileUpload doesn't work in IE. It works fine in Firefox. Is there any solution for this.

I can achieve the same in FileUploadEvent by first uploading the file and then check the size. But I want to do something like in fire fox.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the IE don't support AJAX natively. So you should check filesize after upload like you write or you can check what's user browser. If user browser is firefox or chrome (etc.) it's work with sizeLimit parameter, but if you user use IE you should handle it by some method etc.